# Pythagoras with only one known side / Computational geometry

Tags: computational-geometry

Picture of the problem
[image]

I'm working on a coding challenge where, given some amount of coordinates of mountain peeks and cols, I have to calculate how many meters of the mountain is hit by sun rays.

Coding challenge description: https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=861

I've created a Node class with x-coordinates and y-coordinates and put them in a priority queue with the left most coordinates first

```
double totalLength = 0;
Node peak = priorityQueue.poll();
Node col = null;
while (!priorityQueue.isEmpty()) {
    Node nextCoordinates = priorityQueue.poll();
    if (peak.yCo > nextCoordinates.yCo) {
        col = nextCoordinates;
    } else {
        // DO SOME CALCULATIONS 
        peak = nextCoordinates;
    }
}
System.out.println(totalLength);
```

I'm looking for a calculation explained in the picture at the top first, and a possible better solution to the coding challenge second. Thank you

Comment: No need for Pythagoras. `b` can be obtained from simple similar triangles.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you need to sort by `x` descending, i.e. rightmost point first. Process points right to left, keeping track of the current highest peak, initialized to the rightmost point. If a point is below the current peak it can be ignored. Otherwise we calculate the amount of sun left visible on the slope of the new high peak using similar triangles, i.e. the ratio visible slope (what we want) to total slope is equal to the ratio of visible height (new peak height minus current peak height) to total height.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
Sort array of points, P, by x descending

sun = 0
high = 0
for i = 1 to P.length-1
  if P[i].y > P[high].y
    a = P[i].y - P[i-1].y
    b = P[i].x - P[i-1].x
    hdiff = P[i].y - P[high].y
    sun = sun + hdiff*sqrt(a*a+b*b)/a
    high = i
  end
end
```

Translated to Java:

```
static double calculateSun(int[] peaks)
{
  Point[] pts = new Point[peaks.length/2];
  for(int j=0, i=0; i<peaks.length; j++) 
    pts[j] = new Point(peaks[i++], peaks[i++]);

  // Sort by X descending
  Arrays.sort(pts, (p1, p2) -> {return p2.x - p1.x;});

  double sun = 0;    
  for(int h=0, i=1; i<pts.length; i++)
  {
    if(pts[i].y > pts[h].y)
    {
      int a = pts[i].y - pts[i-1].y;
      int b = pts[i].x - pts[i-1].x;
      int hdiff = pts[i].y - pts[h].y;
      sun += hdiff*Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b)/a;        
      h = i;
    }
  }
  return sun;
}
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int[][] tests = {
      { 1100, 1200, 0, 500, 1400, 100, 600, 600, 2800, 0, 
        400,  1100, 1700, 600, 1500, 800, 2100, 300, 
        1800, 700, 2400, 500, },
      {
        0, 1000, 1000, 0, 
      }};

  for (int[] test : tests)
    System.out.printf("%.2f\n", calculateSun(test));
}
```

Output:

```
1446.34
1414.21
```

Which matches the expected output.